# Extension: error use of undeclared type

Tags: swift

I am new to swift, and I would like to create an extension of the Dog class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    public class Dog {
        var name = "Timmy"
    }
}

extension Dog {
    func description() -> String {
        return "A dog named \(self.name)"
    }
}
```

I thought extensions go at the way bottom, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dog class is "hidden" inside your ViewController class. Declare it at top level or refer to it as `ViewController.Dog`.

Comment: And see, if you like, my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_namespaces

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have declared a class (`Dog`) inside another class (`ViewController`) - which is a *don't* in the first place - and so the class is not visible outside the other. Also, you don't *have to* put an extension at the very end of a file.

#### Solution

Move the class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { ... }

class Dog {}

extension Dog {}
```

#### Solution #2

Change how you refer to the class:

```
extension ViewController.Dog {}
```